# RuntimeException: Operation not permitted, failed to write trailer. When using IMediaWriter

Tags: java, xuggle

I am having an error when using `IMediaWriter.close();` from Xuggle.
relevant code of [Main Class](http://hastebin.com/wuvigiqexi.avrasm):

```
 protected IMediaWriter WRITER = ToolFactory.makeWriter(OUTPUT_FILE);
 protected static final String OUTPUT_FILE = "C:/Users/Ryan.D/Desktop/fileTest.mp4";
 protected void stopThreads() {
    textField.setBackground(Color.RED);
    capture = false;
    try {
        thread.join();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    WRITER.addVideoStream(0, 0, ICodec.ID.CODEC_ID_MPEG4, SCREEN_BOUNDS.width / 2, SCREEN_BOUNDS.height / 2);
    long startTime = System.nanoTime();
    for (int index = 0; index < (FRAME_TIME * images.size()) * FRAME_RATE; index++) {
        BufferedImage converted = convert(images.get(index), BufferedImage.TYPE_3BYTE_BGR);
        WRITER.encodeVideo(0, converted, System.nanoTime() - startTime, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS);
        try {
            Thread.sleep((long) (1000 / FRAME_RATE));
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    WRITER.flush();
    WRITER.close();
}
```

[Error](http://hastebin.com/beyoyeriku.avrasm):

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.RuntimeException: error Operation not permitted, failed to write trailer to C:/Users/Ryan.D/Desktop/fileTest.mp4
```

I am not sure why this is happening, I have looked around for a solution but most of the other solutions relate to Audio whereas mine is just Video.

Thanks
Ryan.

Comment: How did you solve it then?

Comment: @Jatin I am not sure how I did this and the main class has expired but I will see if I can figure it out. This was 4 months ago so I can't remember what project this was from. If you give me a couple of days I will see if I can figure out the problem. Sorry about that.

Comment: @Jatin I have no idea if this was the problem but when running this, I only added `capture = true` and some output statements and it seems to work now. [Here is the class](http://pastebin.com/2fLuf9tc) because it shows the main method too. I am not sure if I was just being stupid and not setting captured to true or if it was something else because the main class has expired on hastebin.

Comment: Thanks a lot for response :). Turns out that I was not writing anything to the file and closing it. hence the error (This was because I had a while loop as `while(!Thread.currentThread.isInterrupted())){}`. The interrupt status was getting cleared automatically. My code: http://pastebin.com/HvBMDYtT

Comment: @Jatin No problem! Glad you got it sorted.